# getting through 665 Error that prevents database backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, event-log

When trying to do a back up of a database it fails at 30 percent. I try to defrag the disk to solve the problem but it still fails in the same step. I would like to understand why it failed.

Backup failed for Server 'Servernamehere'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Write on "E:\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSAS10.MSSQLSERVER\Backup\FrameProcess\FrameProcess.bak"
>   failed: 665(The requested operation could not be completed due to a
>   file system limitation) (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Comment: How big is the database in question? Do you have compression turned on the DBMS? How much space is available when you defrag? Does the database have an active snapshot?

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem: backup fails with error message 665.

The cause was excesive disk fragmentation.

Please see:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002606

We run Windows Defrag on all the disks and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

One cause of this error can be using folder compression. If you are using it, try backing up to a non-compressed folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this? http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;957065

You don't specify the OS, but the symptoms sound similar.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check that on disk level:-

Any fragmentation and Shrinking is running on required interval. If yes, disable it to resolve the issue. Ask the Server team to do it if you can't.

I had same issue and its got resolved after disabling the disk.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this error by specifying multiple files in the backup instead of one big file. The whole backup is around 60GB, I split it into 12 5GB files and the error went away.

Later on, I checked the fragmentation level for that particular disk and it was showing around 40% fragmentation. It might be related as stated in previous answers.